# Using <leader> with :normal

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When using `:normal` how do I simulate typing out the leader key?

I want to do something like:

```
:normal <leader>J
```

This is for a plugin I'm writing, so I can't just type out the leader key directly...I need an indirect way to reference it.

Comment: You press the leader key.

Comment: @romainl this is for a plugin I'm writing, so I won't know what the user's leader key is...

Comment: You should add that info to your question.

Comment: @romainl thanks...I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with other special keys, you'll need `:exe` + `"\<keyname>"` (double quotes (not single ones) + antislash)

```
:exe "normal \<leader>J"
```